# Get specific content from a website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I would like to get content from another website using JavaScript. I allready searched for code snippets and i found this http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_responsetext 
I changed some values, that it would work for the website i use. When i ran this code the browser tells me that I was not allowed to get the content from this website, so i inserted: "header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://....")" in the php section of the website and it worked but it displayed all the content of the page, now i would like to filter a div out of all the content and display only that div. Is there an easy way to do this using JS/Jquery?

Here is my code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://.....", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I guess the problem is that i have to load the content from the other website first, and then run a piece of code that filters the content in the demo block.

Comment: "Is there an easy way...to filter...." - not "Easy", per-se.  What do you want to "filter"?  Where you have this `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`, you'd do something like this `var content = xmlhttp.responseText; // filter content with your code here ; document.getElementById("demo") = content;`

Comment: @cale_b should add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there an easy way...to filter...."

Not "easy", per-se. What do you want to "filter"?

In order to edit / manipulate the information returned, where you have this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

You'd do something like this:

```
var content = xmlhttp.responseText; 
// filter content with your code here;
document.getElementById("demo") = content;
```

NOTE: If you are using jQuery (your question includes the jQuery tag), then the code becomes simpler:

```
jQuery.ajax("http://www.urltoajax.com", {
    success: function(content) {
            // filter content with your code here
            // Example:
            content = $(content).find('my_elem').text();
            // Then apply / append it to the element.
            jQuery("#demo").html(content);
        }
});
```